# lscpu list different max cpu freq

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, utilities, temperature, lscpu

Is this a bug from lscpu?
How to fix it?

```
~$ lscpu
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          20
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-19
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              12
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           151
Model name:                      12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-12700
Stepping:                        2
CPU MHz:                         2096.531
CPU max MHz:                     6300.0000
CPU min MHz:                     800.0000
```

This is an Intel i7-12700, it lists the CPU max MHz is `6300.0000`

However, I checked the Intel website, and it lists:

```
Max Turbo Frequency
4.90 GHz

Intel® Turbo Boost Max Technology 3.0 Frequency ‡
4.90 GHz

Performance-core Max Turbo Frequency
4.80 GHz

Efficient-core Max Turbo Frequency
3.60 GHz

Performance-core Base Frequency
2.10 GHz

Efficient-core Base Frequency
1.60 GHz
```

ref:
https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/134591/intel-core-i712700-processor-25m-cache-up-to-4-90-ghz.html

OS version:

```
~$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Comment: What is the question here exactly? Yes, it looks like `lscpu` is reporting the wrong value. Are you asking if this is a problem? How to fix it? If it is a bug? Could you please [edit] and add a question so we know what to answer?